# why jenkins return 500 error while uploading npm build to nexus?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, cicd

I got this error in jenkins logs , what is the reason I've got this error while building and uploading my npm project to nexus and also what is the solution in this case?

```
'http fetch PUT 500 
http://172.**.***.***:8081/repository/front/project1 73402ms a ttempt 
 #3
verbose stack Error: 500 Server Error - PUT http://172.**.***.***:8081/repository/front/project1l
verbose stack     at /var/jenkins_home/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/check-response.js:117:15
verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
verbose statusCode 500
verbose pkgid izboom-developerportal@1.1.16149
verbose cwd /var/jenkins_home/workspace/project1
verbose Linux 3.10.0-1160.76.1.el7.x86_64
verbose argv "/var/jenkins_home/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/bin/node" "/var/jenkins_home/.nvm/versions/node/v14.20.0/bin/npm" "publish"
verbose node v14.20.0
verbose npm  v6.14.17
error code E500
error 500 Server Error - PUT http://172.**.***.***:8081/repository/front/project1
verbose exit [ 1, true ]'
```

Comment: Http 500 means something went wrong on receiving server. Most likely jenkins has nothing to do with it. Go check nexus logs, and investigate it from there.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that i've been using, change the placeholders and you should be able to do it, if you want to go with your own approach, can you show the sh/bat step you are using to upload file.

```
curl -v -u %NEXUS_USR%:%NEXUS_PSW% --upload-file "%WORKSPACE%\\deployment\\%buildName%.zip" %nexus_repo_path%/<repo-name>/
```

Here the NEXUS_USR and NEXUS_PSW are taken from the interpolated credentials variable using the credential manager, something like this in the environment section.

```
NEXUS = credentials('NEXUS_CREDENTIALS')
```